# How to get list of permissions in a role

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I'm using `Romanbican/Roles` laravel package, and I have `permission_role` table, `roles` table, and `permissions` table. Now, I want to get all `permissions` of a specific `role`. e.g. (role: `Admin`, permissions: `create.users`, `delete.users`, `edit.users`. The result would be:
**Admin:**

- create.users
- delete.users
- edit.users

how can I do that? Here's my tables with fields:

**roles**

---

id | name | slug | level |

---

**permissions**

---

id | name | slug |

---

**permission_role**

---

id | permission_id | role_id |

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'll need a controller to handle this. The controller must be able to get the role, then it needs to look after the perms by the role and then get the permissions.

So it would look something like this;

```
public function editRolePerms($id)
    {
      $getrole = Role::findOrFail($id);

      $permbyrole = DB::table('permission_role')->select('permission_id')->where('role_id', $id)->lists('permission_id');

      $getperms = Permission::all();

      return view('your_view')->with('role', $getrole)->with('getperms', $getperms)->with('permbyrole', $permbyrole);
    }
```

That would be the controller, then to get the perms by the roles in your view, it would look something like this:

```
@foreach($getperms as $perm)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $perm->name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $perm->description }}</td>
  @if(!in_array($perm->id, $permbyrole))
      <td><span id="{{ $perm->id }}" class="label label-danger">Not enabled</span></td>
      <td><input onclick="toggleRole({{ $perm->id }}, {{ $role->id }})" type="checkbox" id="checkbox_{{ $perm->id }}"></td>
  @else
      <td><span id="{{ $perm->id }}" class="label label-success">Enabled</span></td>
      <td><input onclick="toggleRole({{ $perm->id }}, {{ $role->id }})" type="checkbox" checked="true" id="checkbox_{{ $perm->id }}"></td>
  @endif
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Hope this suits your need.

Comment: I'll try your solution

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with it.

Comment: Yah! :)  arigato

Comment: One more thing, what is the use of `lists()` method? is it returning the database `field`?

Comment: I mean the value of that field?

Comment: What if I want to attach only `permissions` with checked?  and `detach` the permission without check?

Comment: I mean the saving part?

Comment: hm, I want to **attach** all `checked` `permissions` and  **detach** all `unchecked` `permissions`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Make relationship in Role model file

```
public function permissions()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Permissions::class, 'permission_role', 'role_id', 'permission_id ')
}
```

Comment: I'll try it sir.

Comment: hmm it returns `Collection {#217 ▼
  #items: []
}` but I have 1 record in my database